# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: 'ion-col' is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am trying to create a custom component in ionic 3 but i do not seem to know how to setup the components.module properly so that i can use the ionic components in my component

i generated the component like so

```
 $: ionic g component my-component
```

When i add

```
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row
```

to `my-component.html` i get the error

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: 'ion-col' is not
>   a known element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using

```
ionic generate component my-component
```

It'll automatically be declared inside the shared module `components.module.ts` under the `components` folder.

So if you need to use that component, just import above shared module inside your page's module.

`components.module.ts` (*shared*)

```
 import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';

 @NgModule({
    declarations:[MyComponentComponent],
    imports:[
       IonicPageModule.forChild(MyComponentComponent)  // <- Add
    ],
    exports: [MyComponentComponent]
 })
```

Comment: Oh..Hope you're not using latest CLI no? If you use it, this is automatic or by default it does it :)

Comment: 2 years later if anyone happens to stumble on the same issue, just try adding IonModule to the modules imports and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `ionic g component my-component`

It'll automatically create a components folder and declared inside the shared module `components.module.ts`

To use that component, you need to import `components.module.ts` inside your page's module.

For exemple you want to load it in `MyFirstPage` a simple ionic page :

```
 import { ComponentsModule } from "./your-path/components/components.module";
 import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';

 @NgModule({
    declarations:[
       MyFirstPage
    ],
    imports:[
       ComponentsModule,
       IonicPageModule.forChild(MyFirstPage),
    ],
    exports: [
       ComponentsModule
    ]
 })
```